# Autolayout expand label when press button

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, autolayout

I'm developing iOS 6 application and using Autolayout. My interface is very simple: label and button verticale aligned. Label has very long text but it's height is set to 50. I want to expand the label when the button is pressed. I try to make it but when the label is expanded the button is not moved. I want vertical space between them to be constant. My button action code look like this:

```
- (IBAction)touch:(id)sender {
    [self.label sizeToFit];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can connect UI Elements via interface builder.

Check out this tutorial

http://www.raywenderlich.com/20897/beginning-auto-layout-part-2-of-2

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I should set height of the length to be greater than or equal not equal